How do I access the address dynamically in NASM?
loop:
            mov rax, SYS_WRITE
            mov rdi, STDOUT
            mov rsi, newLine
            mov rdx, newLineLength
            syscall
            
            ; PATIENT 1
            mov rsi, 0                          ; reset rsi
            lea rsi, [record + (printLoop * patient_record)] 
            mov r8, rsi
            call print_detail
            inc byte[printLoop]

            cmp byte[printLoop], bl
            jne loop
            jmp main_menu



I have this code and i keep on getting errors on the lea line :
error: invalid effective address: impossible segment base multiplier
But if I change the printLoop to a constant multiplier (e.g. 0), it runs. What seems could be the problem? This is a loop so I wish to run this at most 5 times
Basically, I want to access the structs dynamically
I changed the printLoop to constant multiplier and it works but as I want it to loop, i use printLoop variable as my multiplier and increments every loop but it gives invalid effective address error

Consult a manual about allowed addressing modes. You will need to do the multiplication separately. Or, since you are looping sequentially, just increment a pointer instead.
